# How does the concentration of a gas affect the entropy of a system in a chemical equilibrium?

Tags: concentration, entropy

The question asks about factors that increase the entropy of the system. The mark-scheme states that "decreasing the concentration of a gas without changing the volume of the container" is the answer. I do not understand how that is possible.

The chemical equilibrium of the question is the decomposition of calcium carbonate:
CaCO3(s)  CaO(s) + CO2(g)

My thoughts are that in order to decrease the concentration of the gas without changing the volume, the equilibrium would have to shift to the left. But that would correspond to a lesser amount of gas, so a lower entropy.

My next thought was that the mark-scheme I had was wrong. I did some digging and found that the question had 3 "G2" complaints, meaning that 3 IB chem teachers had complained about the question during the examination period. But yet the IB determined that the question was fair and kept it, and so here I am trying to wrap my mind around the topic. Alas, I am in need of some help.
[image]

Comment: What is the question statement?

Comment: Ahh. I completely forgot to add what the question was asking for! Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I agree with your line of thought. Can you add a link to those complaints or other specifics? Perhaps more detail regarding the nature of the question too.

Comment: That helps to know that I'm not missing something glaring. I've added what I have about the complaints. I'm now thinking that the "concentration decreasing" in this question might be referring to diffusion. If it is, then what a terrible question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "decreasing the concentration of the gas" is supposed to imply "adding an inert gas to the container", which would certainly increase the entropy. (This process would be equivalent to a fraction, say half, of the carbon dioxide molecules suddenly becoming nitrogen molecules, and then having the two gases mix. The entropy of mixing is positive.)

This is indeed poor wording.